# Issue in react-routing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react routing in my project. Sample below -

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
    <Route path="/admin/clients" element={<Clients/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And in one of my components I am using -

```
<Link to="/admin/clients" key={icon.id}>
  <div onClick={e => clickHandler(e, icon)} className='nav__tab'>
    <div>{ icon.src }</div>
    <span className='nav__name'>{icon.name}</span>
  </div>
</Link>
```

Above code is redirecting me to the next page with the correct link (admin/clients) which is fine.

However, since it is redirecting me to the new link(admin/clients), I am not able to reuse my navigation buttons that I created.

Screenshots below -

This is my navigation component -

[image]

And when I click on Clients, it is redirecting me to the new page -

[image]

I want to be on the page(with navigation on the left just like in the screenshot) and the client component should be on the right hand side.

Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your navigation component from one of the routed components, i.e. `Admin`, out to be unconditionally rendered outside of the routes.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
    <Route path="/admin/clients" element={<Clients />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If there's a need to render the `Navbar` on only specific routes then create a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) component that renders the `Navbar` component and an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />

    <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
      <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
      <Route path="/admin/clients" element={<Clients />} />
      ... routes with navbar ...
    </Route>

    ... routes without navbar ...
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have created that navigation within `Admin` component. You should use `React router` with `Layouts` feature which create a Layout outside and all the children routes will have same layout.

Please check below link for more understanding.

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/new-approach-for-working-with-react-router-dom-82b7be0404b9